# Google Sheets Macro not completing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, macro-recorder

I'm trying to parse a CSV file using Google Sheets macros. I've recorded all the steps as individual macros, and one by one they work fine, but when I combine into one macro, it doesn't run properly. The point at which it stops working is after the `PODdateformatting` part has completed and it's run through the first three lines of `Daystodeliverformula`. Cell H2 is populated with the formula, but the formula doesn't then autofill down the rest of the column. Any ideas? Or indeed, am I going about this all wrong and need a good talking to? :-)

```js
function TheWholeShebang() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // start of DeletedUnwantedColumns
  spreadsheet.getRange('AA:DE').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  spreadsheet.getRange('W:X').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  spreadsheet.getRange('R:U').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:P').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('P1'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('E1'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()); // end of DeletedUnwantedColumns

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // start of Addcolumnsandheaderlabels
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:F').activate(); 
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn(), 6);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 6).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('POD Date (formatted)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Days to Deliver');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate(); // end of Addcolumnsandheaderlabels

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // start of PODdateformatting
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate()
  .setFormula('=DATE(LEFT(D2,4),mid(D2,5,2),right(D2,2))');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES); // end of PODdateformatting

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //start of Daystodeliverformula
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate()
  .setFormula('=NETWORKDAYS(E2,G2,Instructions!$B$15:$B$40)-1');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES); // end of Daystodeliverformula
};
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a test sheet with the above code? The code is clumsy being produced by combining macros and could be reduced a lot. `AutoFilltoNeighbour` depends on data in adjacent column so its hard to see just from code what is happening....

Comment: @bcperth Thanks for the reply - I fully expected it to be viewed as messy as I basically recorded a bunch of individual macros (each of which works in isolation) and them lumped them together into one to see if I could do it all in one operation!) Link to test spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBYPc9DFMkfW53zZ82Mrfio3Sq_te4qRlGE3YKLwtno/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tested extensively but could not make it work. See here for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229644/any-ideas-of-why-autofilltoneighbor-works-only-for-the-first-column-i-use-it.  see additional comment below...

Comment: I think there is a problem in Google scripts with running multiple autoFillToNeighbor() methods in succession in a script. WHen I ran thewholeshebang() H2 was not autofilled. But when I ran Daystodeliverformula() separately after TheWholeShebang() it filled H correctly. Go figure!  This is a google scripts bug unless there is something documented we are both missing.... I also put delays between the autoFillToNeighbor() but made no difference.

Comment: Ok I found a way to make it all work.. see reply below. Comments above are still applicable but see more notes in the reply...

Answer (score 1):

After messing about with `range.autoFillToNeighbor()` and failing (see comments above) I was still suspicious about that method.

When I used this the `range.autoFill()` method instead it all worked fine. See code below.

```
  // start of PODdateformatting
  //var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate().setFormula('=DATE(LEFT(D2,4),mid(D2,5,2),right(D2,2))');
  var sourceRange = spreadsheet.getRange("G2:G2");
  var destination = spreadsheet.getRange("G2:G369");
  sourceRange.autoFill(destination,SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

  //start of Daystodeliverformula
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate().setFormula('=NETWORKDAYS(E2,G2,Instructions!$B$15:$B$40)-1');
  var sourceRange = spreadsheet.getRange("H2:H2");
  var destination = spreadsheet.getRange("H2:H369");
  sourceRange.autoFill(destination,SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

In hindsight I now believe that `range.autoFillToNeighbor()` was never right for your use case in the first place!

`range.autoFillToNeighbor()` expects to build autofill formulas based on data that is contained in **neighbouring columns**. It tries to do this intelligently, but neighbouring columns do not contain anything useful! Its amazing it ever worked... maybe **sometimes** defaulting to `range.autoFill()`!

`range.autoFill()` on the other hand, just duplicates the formula (data) above or below ( NOT looking to neighbouring cells for help).

You can copy and paste these over the corresponding functions in function `TheWholeShebang()` and should all work.

Note I assume a fixed range of `369` as per your data, but you can calculate this based on actual size if you prefer, in case no of rows is changed.

Comment: Cheers, really appreciate your help. Funny that the very function thing that the Google Sheets macro recorder records  - [range.autoFilltoNeighbor()] is seemingly not the right function to use, but works when you run the macros on their own! Anyway, thanks for your assistance - I'll jump back into the original Sheets file when I'm in the office on Monday and try it out! :D

Comment: OK great. Consider to accept the reply, when you are happy it all works. Accept is the tick on top left of reply under the vote up/down arrows.